# Can Web Essentials 2012 display regions with names in javascript files?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-essentials

Searched for an answer but did not find any...

adding a region such as

```
#region XXXXXX
   .
   . {code here}
   .
#endregion
```

collapses into

[image]

is it **not** possible to name regions? Quite downgrades the feature... you end up having several collapsed areas in your code and you have no idea what they do (unless you add comments above them...)

Comment: I don't see why this question "shows no research efforts" or might be "not useful"... did not find any answers for it, and I think the question is nothing less than legitimate: if the feature was taken from VS IDE's regions, not being able to name them does not make them as useful as in VS IDE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone from my team solved the issue...

here is the answer:

[image]

[image]

I was adding a space between the double slashes and the "#region" directive...
Removing that space... makes the region name be displayed.